# git pager=cat missing a newline at the end

Tags: git

I've set `core.pager=cat`, however it doesn't insert a newline at the end of the output, so that the new prompt appears on the same line as the last line of git's output.

How can I fix that?

example:

```
Lohoris@Pelociccio /cygdrive/d/work/MixArt$ git lo
* d42d527 2012-05-14 18:58:38 +0200 | Hidden: diff_find e diff_shown (XDK: v0.0.8) (HEAD, origin/master, master) [Lorenzo Petrone]
* 3829928 2012-05-14 18:28:38 +0200 | Hidden.diff_all (XDK: v0.0.7) [Lorenzo Petrone]
[...]
* 9a033bb 2012-05-14 10:35:29 +0200 | fix Hidden [Lorenzo Petrone]
* eb2d57d 2012-05-11 18:23:02 +0200 | crash() [Lorenzo Petrone]Lohoris@Pelociccio /cygdrive/d/work/MixArt$
```

notice how the new prompt is on the same line of the last git output line.

Comment: `cat` doesn't append extra characters. Which `git` command are you using that is failing to terminate its last line correctly?

Comment: @CharlesBailey this alias `lo = log --pretty=format:\"%h %ai | %s%d [%an]\" --graph --date=short -n 12`

Comment: Wow. This question is a near 100% specific match to my situation. Good to know it was an issue with me, and not git.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your issue is with `--pretty:format` and not with your pager. You probably want to use `tformat` instead of `format` to provide the terminator semantics that you are looking for.

Try:

```
git log --pretty=tformat:"%h %ai | %s%d [%an]" --graph --date=short -n 12
```